# How to connect 2 routers together, have one for internet connection and the other for the NAS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

I currently have a Netgear WNDR3400v2 and a Comcast Xfinity TC8305C Wireless Cable modem connected together. I have done this for one reason and one alone. To get to my NAS drive connected to the Netgear router. I have disabled SSID broadcast on the Netgear and use is solely for backing up files. This is the question I would like to ask: How can I connect the 2 routers together and still have access to my NAS when connected to the Xfinity router? The only way I can get access now is to be connected to the Netgear router. The Netgear points to the Xfinity router as the default gateway and I have my patch cable running from one of the LAN ports on the Xfinity router to the WAN port on the Netgear router. If anyone could help me out here I would be most appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be connecting to the WAN port on the Netgear router since you are not connecting it to a WAN! The connection should be LAN-to-LAN, the Netgear router's DHCP server should be disabled, and the Netgear router should be assigned a static IP address that is valid on the cable modem's LAN but outside its DHCP assignment range.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ive done what you've said before I made this post and I couldn't log into the netgear router to change anything once I disable DHCP because it's unable to assign any IP's. How do I get around this?

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question. Ok, I've got the DHCP server turned off on the Netgear but I have ran into another problem. When I try to assign a static IP to the Netgear within the Comcast router it won't let me do it. It keeps telling me it's outside the range in red text and won't take the setting. My comcast router by default uses 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.255 as it's IP pool. I tried using 10.0.100.2 along with many others and it won't let me. So I guess it's not possible to tie these two together to accomplish what I need to do? Thanks again for your help..

Comment: OK, got it all figured out. Used 10.0.0.101 as a static for the Netgear and set the scope for the Xfinity router to end at 100. Turned DHCP off on the Netgear and then connected my patch cable to a LAN port on each router. Im in business now. Thanks for the help David. I appreciate it..